# How to ensure SQL database design will be cross platform

Tags: sql, standards, ansi-sql

I am working on a project where my current development environment is based on MySQL, while the production environment may be either MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server. I am trying to make sure that the SQL I am writing to build my database tables will be cross platform.

I have already found that the ZEROFILL attribute is non-standard, so I am assuming that it would not be available outside of MySQL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE
 `scfe`.`tbl_UserRoles` ( 
 `UserRoleRecID` INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'User Role Rec ID' ,
 `UserADID` CHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User ADID FK - tbl_Users.UserADID' ,
 `UserRole` CHAR(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User Role FK - systbl_SYS_Roles.UserRoleID' ,
 `Status` ENUM('A','I') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'I' COMMENT 'User Role Status - A = Active, I = Inactive // Default = I' ,
`RoleDateAdded` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
`RoleDateModified` DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
PRIMARY KEY (`UserRoleRecID`), 
INDEX `Index_UserADID` (`UserADID`), 
INDEX `Index_UserRole` (`UserRole`), 
INDEX `Index_RoleStatus` (`Status`))
 ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

As I want to make sure that the code will easily transition between systems, are there other features/options that would not be cross-platform (for example, based on the code above is there a default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`? the on update Are there alternatives that should be used?

I know that the engine line would not need to be used outside of MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you recommend a tool or reference on converting between the two. As noted, since I do not know the final destination platform I am trying to not use platform dependent features.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can write a single CREATE TABLE statement that works the same with MySQL and SQL Server and results in what you have now, e.g. generating an ID would require an `identity(...)` option in SQL Server where you use `auto_increment` in MySQL. Neither of those options are standard SQL (that would be `generated always as identity`).

Data types are the next problem. Especially datetime/timestamp types are sufficiently different that you won't have much luck there. Btw: stop using `char()` - that type has only disadvantages and absolutely no advantages whatsoever.

There is no way you can use something like an ENUM in a cross-DBMS design. Use a lookup table instead.

Constraints and indexes are the next problem. Column and table comments as well (SQL Server only "supports" them by calling a stored procedure that stores "extended attributes).

I would recommend to use e.g. [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) with the XML format which can easily be used against a variety of database products. e.g. Liquibase knows how to create a "generated ID" column if you use `autoIncrement="true"` - it will use `auto_increment` for MySQL, `identity()` for SQL Server and `serial` for Postgres.

If you use "standard JDBC" data types, Liquibase also know how to translate them. e.g. `timestamp` will become `datetime` in SQL Server.

Your statement would result in something along the lines of:

```xml
<!-- lookup table for status -->
<createTable tableName="role_status"  schemaName="scfe" remarks="User Role Status - A = Active, I = Inactive // Default = I">
  <column name="status_id" type="integer">
    <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_role_status" />
  </column>
  <column name="status_code" type="varchar(1)" />
</createTable>

<createTable tableName="user_roles" schemaName="scfe">
  <column name="userrolerecid" type="integer" autoIncrement="true" remarks="User Role Rec ID">
    <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_user_roles" />
  </column>
  <column name="useradid" type="varchar(50)" remarks="User ADID FK - tbl_Users.UserADID">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
  </column>
  <column name="user_role" type="varchar(150)" remarks="User Role FK - systbl_SYS_Roles.UserRoleID'">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
  </column>
  <column name="status_id" type="varchar(1)">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
  </column>
  <column name="role_date_added" type="timestamp">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
  </column>
  <column name="role_date_modified" type="timestamp"/>
</createTable>

<addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_user_role2status" 
                         baseTableName="user_roles" 
                         baseColumnNames="status_id" 
                         referencedTableName="role_status" 
                         referencedColumnNames="status_id" />

<addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_user_role2role" 
                         baseTableName="user_roles" 
                         baseColumnNames="user_role" 
                         referencedTableName="roles" 
                         referencedColumnNames="user_role_id" />

<addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_user_role2adid" 
                         baseTableName="user_roles" 
                         baseColumnNames="useradid" 
                         referencedTableName="users" 
                         referencedColumnNames="useradid" />

<createIndex indexName="index_useradid" tableName="user_roles">
  <column name="useradid"/>
</createIndex>

<createIndex indexName="index_userrole" tableName="user_roles">
  <column name="user_role"/>
</createIndex>

<createIndex indexName="index_rolestatus" tableName="user_roles">
  <column name="status_id"/>
</createIndex>
```

This can be extended to cope with things that need to be DBMS specific (e.g. a data type for `UUID`) either by using parameters or by only running certain things on against specific DBMS products (e.g. to create check constraints or special index types)